# PHP: What does CURLOPT_URL really do?

Tags: php, curl

I'm new to curl library. Google solves most of my questions such as how to execute a curl. However, there is one thing still confuses me, that is when we set

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://example.com')
```

will curl download the content from the targeted website? if not, then how curl posts the content? Thanks!

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_URL.html

Comment: hmm.. it just explains how to use curl and elaborate several types of protocols.. still don't get my answer here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical session of [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) in PHP looks like this:

```
// Initialize curl
$ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com');

// Configure curl as needed, depending on your application
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    'CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION' => TRUE,
    'CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER' => TRUE,
    'CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT' => 3,
    // ... other options here ...
));

// Do the request
$page = curl_exec($ch);

// Cleanup
curl_close($ch);
```

Sometimes you may want to do several requests using the same options. For subsequent requests you can repeat the code above with a different URL (or encapsulate it in a function for convenience).

Or you can reuse the existing resource and issue multiple requests before closing it.

To do this call [`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to change the URL then call [`curl_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) again to get the new page.

Repeat these two steps as many times as you need before calling [`curl_close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-close.php).

---

To answer your question, `curl_setopt()` and `curl_setopt_array()` only prepare the `curl` object and the HTTP request. `curl_exec()` is the function that actually sends the request and returns (or displays) the content it receives.

Comment: Thanks! Helps a lot!